# What am I doing wrong when trying to implement an array of strings?

Tags: c, memory, dynamic, struct, allocation

```
typedef struct ArrayList
{
    // We will store an array of strings (i.e., an array of char arrays)
    char **array;

    // Size of list (i.e., number of elements that have been added to the array)
    int size;

    // Length of the array (i.e., the array's current maximum capacity)
    int capacity;

} ArrayList;
```

The following function is supposed to dynamically allocate memory for an array of strings supported by a header file which contains a struct (see above):

```
void panic(char *s)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "%s", s);
    exit(1);
}

ArrayList *createArrayList(int length){
    ArrayList *n = malloc(sizeof(ArrayList));

    int initial = 0, i;

    if (length > DEFAULT_INIT_LEN)
    {
        n->array = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(int*));
        n->capacity = length;

        for (i = 0; i< n->capacity; i++)
        {
            n->array[i] = NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        n->array = (char **)malloc(DEFAULT_INIT_LEN * sizeof(int*));
        n->capacity = DEFAULT_INIT_LEN;

        for (i = 0; i< n->capacity; i++)
        {
            n->array[i] = NULL;
        }
    }

    if (n->array == NULL)
        panic("ERROR: out of memory in Mylist!\n");

    n->size = initial;

    printf("-> Created new ArrayList of size %d\n", n->capacity);
    return n;
}
```

Then I have another function that is supposed to print all of the strings currently in the newly allocated array created by the createArrayList function:

```
void printArrayList(ArrayList *list)
{
    int i;

    for(i=0; i<list->capacity; i++)
    {
        if (list->array[i] == NULL)
            printf("(empty list)\n");
        else
            printf("%s\n",list->array[i]);

    }
}
```

When I implement the printArrayList function (above) in my main function, the output is:

```
-> Created ArrayList of size 10 
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
```

However, if i insert `strcpy(n->array[1], "apple");` in the createArrayList function as a means of testing the 2D array's ability to hold strings the output is:

```
-> Created ArrayList of size 10
```

...and then it crashes

So my question is what am I doing wrong? Am I incorrectly allocating memeory for my array? I want to get it so the output is:

```
-> Created ArrayList of size 10 
(empty list)
apple
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
(empty list)
```

Comment: Not the main bug, but you should allocate length * sizeof(char*), not length * sizeof(int*).

Answer (score 1):

As well as allocating memory for `ArrayList`, you also need to allocate storage for each string.  If you want to set the second element of the array, you could do this using something like

```
void insert_at(ArrayList* arraylist, const char* str, int index)
{
    arraylist->array[index] = malloc(strlen(str)+1);
    if (arraylist->array[index] != NULL) {
        strcpy(arraylist->array[index], str);
    }
}
```

and call it like

```
insert_at(n, 1, "apple");
```

As an aside, your code like

```
n->array = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(int*));
```

should be

```
n->array = malloc(length * sizeof(char*));
```

(Its an array of pointers to `char` rather than `int` and you shouldn't cast the return from `malloc` in C)

Comment: Or simply arraylist->array[index] = strdup(str).

Comment: @jarmod Yes, if `strdup` is available.  (Its part of Posix but not part of standard C)

Comment: Thanks man, it is all clear now. Its not as simple as slapping in a strcpy statement I see.

Answer (score 0):

3 problems

1) Small: Change

```
n->array = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(int*));
```

to

```
n->array = (char **)malloc(length * sizeof(char*));
```

2) Put your test of `if (n->array == NULL)` direclty after `n->array = (char **)malloc(...`

```
n->array = (char **)malloc(DEFAULT_INIT_LEN * sizeof(int*));
if (n->array == NULL)
   panic("ERROR: out of memory in Mylist!\n");
```

3) Most important.  You can not `strcpy(n->array[1], "apple");` without allocating memory for `n->array[1]` first.  Something like

```
n->array[1] = malloc(strlen("Fred")+1);
strcpy(n->array[1], "Fred");
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, I see I have to dynamically allocate for both dimensions then?

Comment: Yes, 1 for the array of pointers and then 'length' allocations, 1 for each of the strings.  Nice you put tests like `if (p == NULL) ...`